# Prove there exist sets $A$, $B$ with $\mathcal P \left({A \cup B}\right) \not= \mathcal P \left({A}\right) \cup \mathcal P \left({B}\right)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove: There exist sets $A$, $B$ with $\mathcal P \left({A \cup B}\right) \not= \mathcal P \left({A}\right) \cup \mathcal P \left({B}\right)$

$\mathcal P$ here is the **[Power Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set)**

Update: With @Simon S and @Stefanos help, I was able to write the following:

> **Proof:**
>
> Let $A = \{a\}$,  $B = \{b\}$, where the element $a\not = b$
>
> $\mathcal P \left({A}\right) = \{ \varnothing, \{a\}\}$
>
> $\mathcal P \left({B}\right) = \{ \varnothing, \{b\}\}$
>
> $\mathcal P \left({A}\right) \cup \mathcal P \left({B}\right) = \{\varnothing,\{a\},\{b\}\}$
>
> $A \cup B = \{a,b\}$
>
> $\mathcal P \left({A \cup B}\right) = \mathcal P \left({\{a,b\}}\right) = \{\varnothing, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{a, b\}\}$
>
> We can see that $\mathcal P \left({A \cup B}\right) \ne \mathcal P
> \left({A}\right) \cup \mathcal P \left({B}\right)$

*Does that look right?*

Comment: What is $P$ here, the power set, the measure/probability? +/union?

Comment: I guess "P" stands for power-set of a given set

Comment: Yeah, it is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A = \{ 0 \}$ and $B = \{ 1 \}$, then $P(A) = \left\{ \emptyset, \{ 0 \} \right\}$ and $P(B) = \left\{ \emptyset, \{ 1 \} \right\}$ while

$$P( A \cup B ) = \left\{ \emptyset, \{ 0 \}, \{ 1 \}, \{ 0, 1 \} \right\} \  \neq \ P(A) \cup P(B)$$

Comment: This works if $0\neq 1$.

Comment: This is the same as what the OP did, no?

Comment: @GFauxPas: Yes, but after Simon S & Stefanos helped me.

Comment: For what it's worth, I did post this before Stefanos or the OP lucidgold edited the post with a solution.

Comment: Wouldn't this be the case for any two sets s.t. $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$?

Answer (score 1):

Take two elements $a,c$ such that $a \in A$ but $a \notin B$ and $c \in B$, but $c \notin A$. Then $$\{a,c\}\in \mathcal P(A\cup B)$$ but $$\{a,c\}\notin \mathcal P(A) \quad \text{ and } \quad \{a,c\}\notin \mathcal P(B)$$ which implies that $$\{a,c\}\notin \mathcal P(A)\cup\mathcal P(B)$$